# Not sure what are gs gu gw cookies

Tags: cookies, web, session-cookies

My website uses _gs _gu _gw cookies
What are these cookies? Why are they used?
I tried looking for this information but can't seem to find it

Comment: It's _your_ website. How would we know better than you? If you are not setting them yourself, are you using any libraries for your website that could be defining them for you?

Comment: It uses google analytics, google optimize, google tag manager and a remarketing tag

Comment: Sure you're not using getsitecontrol?

Answer (score 0):

[This website](https://www.physio-pedia.com/Physiopedia:Cookie_Policy) lists all 3 cookies. It's a specific website policy, but as far as I can see those are cookies used by `Getsitecontrol`, so you can use that description for reference.

- **_gs**  Used to identify the users browser, operating system, IP address and the page on the website they are viewing.
- **_gu**  Used to distinguish users.
- **_gw**  Records widgets previously displayed to user.